# mySQL - 1067 - Invalid default value for 'updated_at'

Tags: mysql, xampp

Trying to upload this `.sql` file but keep getting the the error:

```
1067 - Invalid default value for 'updated_at'
```

I've read many posts where people had same problem. Upgrading `mySQL` and using `timestamp` is sadly not an option.

Would it be possible to remake the code somehow to make it work with `mySQL version: 5.5.16` ?

I know basically nothing about `mySQL`, this is just a quick thing that needs to get uploaded.

I'm on Windows using `xampp`

Here's my code:

```
    -- Create syntax for TABLE 'api_news'
CREATE TABLE `api_news` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`news_title` text NOT NULL,
`news_content` text NOT NULL,
`news_image` text,
`room_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`news_hidden` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'api_news_comments'
CREATE TABLE `api_news_comments` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`message` text NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'api_profile_comments'
CREATE TABLE `api_profile_comments` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`profile_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`message` text NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'api_room_comments'
CREATE TABLE `api_room_comments` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`room_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`message` text NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'api_sessions'
CREATE TABLE `api_sessions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`session` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`expires` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`data` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_session` (`session`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Comment: You need MySQL version 5.6.5 or later to make that work https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: Is that really the only way to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

You could change the field to be a timestamp, but you'll have to handle updates to the `updated_at` within the code yourself.

Change:

```
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

To:

```
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Others have posted a [similar issue](https://github.com/timschofield/webERP-svn/issues/16) that you have encountered relative to the MySQL version.

Info at that link also has a trigger example to update as well, if you don't mind a before update trigger solution as an alternative work-around.